# ubuntu 20.04 does not suspend correctly

Tags: 20.04, suspend

I have a new laptop (MSI GE66 raider) and recently installed ubuntu (dual boot with windows 10).

When I try to suspend my laptop, either by closing the lid or by clicking on the *Suspend* option in the *Power Off / Log Out* settings, some things seem to happen in favor of a suspension but others do not and the computer starts behaving improperly.

Firstly the screen goes black for a second or two but then it comes right back up and the system behaves as follows:

- wifi stops working as its settings disappear
- the whole system becomes a slower and every action has some kind of lag (even if for example I start charging the computer, it will take a few seconds to recognize that it is charging, after suspending)

Also, during boot and shutdown I found the following message that may have something to do with this problem:

> no suspend buffer for PTM

When restarted, the computer starts working properly again.

This situation is very annoying as I do not have the option to just close the laptop lid for a short period of time because I know that when I open it back up I am going to have to shut the system down anyway.

I hope someone can help me fix this issue. Thx!